# Insert assignment operator expression to complete expression in eclipse error

Tags: java, syntax

At line:

```
System.out.println("Welcome to John Doe's shipping calculator!");
```

I get

> "Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete expression" in eclipse

```java
class calc {    
        Shipment s = new Shipment();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to John Doe's shipping calculator!");
        System.out.println("Enter first package dimensions" );
        Package package1 = new Package();
        System.out.println("Enter length");package1.inputLength(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter width");package1.inputWidth(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter height");package1.inputHeight(input.nextDouble());
        Package package2 = new Package();
        System.out.println("Enter second package dimensions" );
        System.out.println("Enter length");package2.inputLength(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter width");package2.inputWidth(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter height");package2.inputHeight(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.print("First package dimensions:" ); package1.displayDimensions();
        System.out.print("Second package dimensions:"); package2.displayDimensions();
        s.cost1 = s.calculateCost(package1);
        s.cost2 = s.calculateCost(package2);
        System.out.println("Package 1 will cost "+  Math.round(s.cost1 * 100.0) /100.0 +  " to ship");
        System.out.println("Package 2 will cost "+ Math.round(s.cost2 * 100.0) /100.0 + " to ship");
        s.display();            
}
```

Why?

Comment: Could you please also show the Package code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print a line (or call a method) directly in your class, try to put it in a method.

```
class calc{
    public void myMethod(){
        Shipment s = new Shipment();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to John Doe's shipping calculator!");
        System.out.println("Enter first package dimensions" );
        Package package1 = new Package();
        //REST OF CODE
    }
}
```

Then call that method where you have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put any commands outside of a method. The only things that can be outside of a method is fields. If you just want to run that, use the main method, which is created like `public static void main(String[] args)`. The main method is always the method that is called to start your program. Another smaller thing is that your class should be capital, and every first letter of a word in your class is capital. So, your `calc` class will look like this:

```
class Calc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Shipment s = new Shipment();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to John Doe's shipping calculator!");
            System.out.println("Enter first package dimensions" );
            Package package1 = new Package();
            System.out.println("Enter length");package1.inputLength(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter width");package1.inputWidth(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter height");package1.inputHeight(input.nextDouble());
            Package package2 = new Package();
            System.out.println("Enter second package dimensions" );
            System.out.println("Enter length");package2.inputLength(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter width");package2.inputWidth(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter height");package2.inputHeight(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.print("First package dimensions:" ); package1.displayDimensions();
            System.out.print("Second package dimensions:"); package2.displayDimensions();
            s.cost1 = s.calculateCost(package1);
            s.cost2 = s.calculateCost(package2);
            System.out.println("Package 1 will cost "+  Math.round(s.cost1 * 100.0) /100.0 +  " to ship");
            System.out.println("Package 2 will cost "+ Math.round(s.cost2 * 100.0) /100.0 + " to ship");
            s.display();
    }
}
```